Independence of CH and permutation models?
Can independence of $\sf CH$ from $\sf ZFCA$ be established using $\sf FM $ permutation models? And if so, then historically did this came first or Cohen's forcing?

No, it cannot. This is because CH is fundamentally a statement about pure sets (= sets not containing urelements in their transitive closures). No independence result for statements about "pure sets" can be established by permutation models, since if ${\bf V}$ is a permutation submodel of ${\bf W}$ then ${\bf V}$ and ${\bf W}$ have the same pure sets.
That said, this same issue does not apply to GCH, at least if phrased loosely as "If $A,B$ are infinite sets and there are injections from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$, then $B$ is equinumerous with either $A$ or $\mathcal{P}(A)$."

But why one should stick to this pure set exposition of the problem? Why not if $A$ is a countable set, then there is no set $B$ that is strictly supernumerous to $A$ and strictly subnumerous to $\mathcal P(A)$. This statement is not  restricted to pure sets, and it seems to be the heart of the issue? Can a permutation model solve this?

@ZuhairAl-Johar Yes, that statement is about pure sets - the issue is the word "countable," meaning "in bijection with $\omega$" (which is a pure set).

Not necessarily,  you can define countable by reference to some non-pure set, that's easy.

@ZuhairAl-Johar These are infinitely movable goalposts. Why don't you write down a precise version of CH you think isn't determined by the pure set part of a ZFA-structure, and then I'll address it?

For example the set of all hereditarily finite sets, call it $\sf HF$, where finite set is defined as being bi-well-orderable, i.e. there is a well ordering on it whose converse relation is a well ordering too. Then phrase the hypothesis as I did above.

@ZuhairAl-Johar In ZFA, your version of HF may be very very large since it will contain each of the atoms. So your version of HF is no longer guaranteed to be countably infinite. I would not consider a version of CH stated for your version of HF to be a faithful rephrasing of CH, to put it mildly.

The issue is not whether you can formulate CH in terms of atoms; the issue is that CH (however you rephrase it) is equivalent to a statement about pure sets. So its truth value cannot be changed without changing the pure part of the universe.

@GabeGoldberg, Ah I see. This is better phrased. So, what you and Noah are saying is that if a statement is equivalent to a statement about pure sets, then it cannot be solved by a permutation model, right!

@NoahSchweber, You can easily take the set of all equivalence classes of finite subsets of $\sf HF$, this would be countable.

@ZuhairAl-Johar And then no different from a pure set, so your version of CH will be equivalent to the usual one which is determined by the pure part and so unaffected by FM-methods.

@NoahSchweber, yes it would be equivalent. But it is not itself a statement about pure sets. Because that set is not pure.

@GabeGoldberg’s comment is the key point here.  As Zuhair is arguing, you can perfectly reasonably define CH in a form that’s not directly in terms of pure sets (and that can happen quite naturally — e.g. if $\mathbb{N}$ is taken axiomatically, not assumed modelled as a von Neumann ordinal).  But it will remain equivalent to a statement about pure sets, and so unchanged by taking permutation models.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, Thank you. What Noah wanted to say is that any statement equivalent to a statement about pure sets then it would be unchanged by permutation models, and so cannot be solved using them. I understand now.

@NoahSchweber Don't Dedekind-finite infinite sets already violate the "loosely phrased" GCH?

@bof Yup! They do indeed (and a lot of other things too).

@NoahSchweber, but can PMs' solve the $\sf HF$ related question (the one you said to be possibly too large) , or we even expect them to solve it?

@NoahSchweber, for the GCH that you've presented, can permutation models have a rule in solving it?
